# react cytoscape js stop animation

Tags: reactjs, animation, cytoscape.js

I forked an existing Cytoscape example to test playing and stopping an animation.
Playing the animation works on "Add node" button, but stopping it fails to stop the animation without any error in the "Add relationship" button.

You will see an alert followed by

```
mySubCyRef.stop();
cy.current.stop();
```

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-cytoscape-forked-jc6yky

What would work to stop all animations

```
(1) without resetting the layout
(2) maintaining the same styles as before the animation started?
```

Comment: Weird. The animation on the AWS node stops for me after clicking "Add relationship" and OK on alert. Could this be browser issues?